# To put content into a JS popup div. Strange issues with the JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got issues to put content into the popup box. I got two buttons into it but no more, nothing else wont work, text for examples.

This is the whole html document

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<center><img id="header" src="../img/hemsidotitle.png"></img></center>
<div id="shadow">
    <div id="navbar">
        <a id="navbar-button" href="../index.html" style="border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px">Hem</a>
        <a id="navbar-button" href="../donera.html">Donera</a>
        <a id="navbar-button" href="#">Kits</a>
        <a id="navbar-button" href="#" style="border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px">Kontakta</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main-container">
        <a onclick="myFunction()" id="kit-drake" class="kit">Click here</a>
        <div id="somethingelse">
        </div>
            <script>
                function submit(){
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<div id="kit-drake-popup" class="pay">TEST<input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Köp Nu" onClick="submit()">TEST</input>test </div>';

                }
            </script>
            <div id="demo"></div>
            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div id="kit-drake-popup" ><input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Avbryt" onClick="submit()"><a id="pay-button" href="#">Köp Nu</a> </div>';
                }
            </script>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="content-center">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is what it looks like when I press the anchor:

[image]

All I want is that the gray button close the popup, the green one just to be an anchor to another page and then be able to put other divs and content, such as text in the popup div (kit-drake-popup). Could this be done in a easy way?

Comment: Why can't you put text in the `<div>` in the popup?

Comment: Try using the jQuery UI Dialog widget.

Comment: You have the jQuery tag, but you're just using plain JS, not jQuery.

Comment: The question I also ask myself, I just can't get it in there. 

It's probably really really simple, I just started to selflearn JS

Comment: I can't figure out how to use your demo, because there's nothing in the `kit-drake` anchor to click on.

Comment: I'm sorry, did not intend to. what's a jQuery UI Dialog widget?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ It's a jQuery plugin for creating popup dialogs with options and other features.

Comment: I'm using a image, but I guess some text would do just for test. U want me to post css or is that irrelevant?

Comment: Alright, I'm testing the jQuery UI widget. How can I make a anchor or button that open it up? I don't want it to be there on page load.

Comment: Give it `display: none` CSS and use the `autoOpen: false` option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation to put text into the popup.

```js
function submit() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<div id="kit-drake-popup" class="pay">TEST<input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Köp Nu" onClick="submit()">TEST</input>test </div>';

}

function myFunction(text) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div id="kit-drake-popup" >' + text + '<br><input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Avbryt" onClick="submit()"><a id="pay-button" href="#">Köp Nu</a > </div>';
}
```

```html
<div id="shadow">
  <div id="main-container">
    <a onclick="myFunction('<div style=\'background-color: yellow; color: blue\'>This is blue text on yellow background.</div>'); return false;" id="kit-drake" class="kit">Click here</a>
    <div id="somethingelse">
    </div>
    <div id="demo"></div>


  </div>
</div>
<div id="content-center">
</div>
```

Comment: Now we are starting to get somewhere, GREAT! But if I would like to place other divs or content inside the popup, how could that be done?

Comment: Whatever you put in place of `Show this text` will be put in there, and it will be rendered as HTML.

Comment: Not really, because the " screws it up. for example:
myFunction('<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"/>') wont work.

Comment: Use single quotes and escape them. Things would be easier if you use Javascript `addEventListener` instead of using inline `onclick` attributes.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show HTML in the function.

Comment: Could I get some help with thoose? Or is that to much to ask? As mentioned earlier I'm a new JS programmer and almost got no knowledge.

Comment: I've gone as far as I'm going to with this. I'm not going to spend all day teaching you Javascript.